# Possible to start Dask in yarn-client mode?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hadoop-yarn, dask, dask-distributed

I use `dask_yarn` (part of `knit`) to start a Dask Yarn cluster as follows:

```
import dask_yarn

cluster = dask_yarn.DaskYARNCluster(env='/home/hadoop/reqs/dvss.zip', lang='en_US.UTF-8')
cluster.start(n_workers=4, memory=5120, cpus=3)
```

This requests 1 vCore on core nodes for AM, and gives the rest of the vCores to workers.

In Spark, I have the option to run the application in `yarn-client` mode, which would have the driver run on master nodes, and then all the core node resources could be free to use by workers. Is it possible to do the same with `dask_yarn`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding the meaning of the two deployment modes in spark.

> There are two deploy modes that can be used to launch Spark applications on YARN. In cluster mode, the Spark driver runs inside an application master process which is managed by YARN on the cluster, and the client can go away after initiating the application. In client mode, the driver runs in the client process, and the application master is only used for requesting resources from YARN.

From this I understand that an ApplicationMaster always exist, and therefore must be allotted *some* resources. The question is whether a separate client process outside of yarn is required or not.

For `knit`, there is also always an ApplicationMaster, and a client process - it effectively  implements client-mode. In addition, the python process, with the Dask scheduler, will be running. This may be a little wasteful, and we would love not to need the (java) client process, but it is small.

As to the requirements for the ApplicationMaster, they are in fact very light by YARN standards. Note that YARN is a resource allocating service and does not actually use up system resources when containers request them.

Comment: My puzzle comes from this: I was running a Spark app and a Dask app on the same EMR cluster with 2 core nodes (c4.2xlarge with 8 vCore) and a master (m4.xlarge, 8 vCore). The Spark app requested and got 4 executors with 4 cores each - 2 executors per node. When I specified 4 workers with 4 cores each for Dask application, it could not allocate them. I assumed this comes from the fact that in client mode, Spark driver and AM use master vCores vs those on core nodes, but Dask doesn't. What really happened?

Comment: It would be worthwhile investigating exactly what yarn has scheduled for the spark case. You can do that via the dashboard or even `knit`'s yarn-api.

Comment: I know it scheduled 4 executors. I took a screenshot of those:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fmrctpi0umt6qh3/yarn-spark-executors1.png?dl=0

Comment: The question is, how does yarn see this allocation

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way to tell?

Comment: Do you mean that cluster manager gave me 4 executor containers, but one of them is actually taken up by the AM?

Comment: The yarn resource manager has its own dashboard that will give you its view on things, or you can get the same information via the yarn_api module in `knit` (any dask_yarn or knit instance also has a yarn_api instance within it, if you look around).